# auth::attempt method not defined

Tags: laravel-5.1, codeception

`Auth` seems to have no method called `attempt`, here is my code, im using `codeception unit test` with cest:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class ReportCest
{
    protected $valid_email = 'email@gmail.com';
    protected $valid_password = 'pass';

    public function _before(UnitTester $I)
    {
        Auth::attempt([
               'email' => $this->valid_email, 
               'password' => $this->valid_password
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` used:

`$this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')`

i wonder how could i implement it like this

Answer (score 0):

after these lines

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
```

type this

```
use Auth;
```

**or** try this way

```
\Auth::attempt(.....
```

Comment: it says undefined class Auth

Comment: remove this line `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` and add `use Auth;` then try

Comment: its the same, auth is undefined, my  was it was not loading the autoloader so it couldn't find the file, btw any Classes i use always says cannot find class

Comment: run this command in your project repo and try again. `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: it says undefined class "Auth", when i use Auth::attempt, and btw there is no attempt method found in any Auth Class

Answer (score 0):

Try this, define Auth before the class definition

```
use Auth;
```